# Order by a field in belongsToMany association

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I got deep associations and i wanted to know if it's possible to order result by a field contained in a BTM association:

```
$modeles = $this->Caracteristiques
        ->find()
        ->contain(['ModeleElements.ModeleOuvrages' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->where([
                    'ModeleOuvrages.couche_id' => 2,
                    'ModeleOuvrages.compte_client_id' => $this->Auth->user('compte_client_id')
                ]);
        }]);
```

Here is my query, i want a resultSet order by the field "nom" in "ModeleOuvrages" association.

Is it possible to get all "caracteristiques" order by "ModeleOuvrages.nom" ?

Edit: i did this:

```
$modeleOuvrages = $this->ModeleOuvrages
        ->find()
        ->where([
            'couche_id' => 2,
            'compte_client_id' => $this->Auth->user('compte_client_id')
        ])
        ->select([
            'ModeleOuvrages.nom',
            'ModeleElements.nom',
            'Caracteristiques.nom',
            'Caracteristiques.type'
        ])
        ->matching('ModeleElements.Caracteristiques')
        ->order(['ModeleOuvrages.nom', 'ModeleElements.nom', 'Caracteristiques.nom']);
```

and it works well. We can also do this with contain with more verbose.

Comment: Is the "where" clause sufficient to guarantee that there will be no more and no less than a single "ModeleOuvrage" for any given "Characteristique" found? If not, then I'm not sure how you would sort on that. If so, then I think what you want is to use "matching" instead of "contain", similar to the answer to a [question I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718606/translating-query-involving-join-table-from-cakephp-1-3-to-3/30721698#30721698).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when using `matching('Deep.Nested.Table')` you will be able to sort on any column of that Table.

Remember that matching will create `INNER JOIN`s and that it could possibly duplicate rows int the result. You can use `$query->distinct(['MainTable.id'])` to remove the duplicates.