# Cakephp 3 inner join with count and group by not working

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'item_requirements.*',
        'COUNT(`item_requirements`.`quantity_required`) as count'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        'INNER JOIN `items` AS item_requirements ON `item_requirements`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`'
    ),
    'group' => '`item_requirements`.`item_id`',
    'contain' => array(
        'items' => array('fields' => array('name', 'specification'))
    )
);
$query = $this->Indents->ItemRequirements->find('all', $options);
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 1: ...item_requirements`.`quantity_required`) AS "counts"" AS "COU... ^

the above error occurs.. any solutions to solve this..

Comment: Can you include the actual SQL query that this generates?

Comment: query

select BB.id item_id, 
BB.code || '-' || BB.sub_code || '-' || BB.name || '-' || BB.specification item_details,
AA.quantity_required consolidated_quantity
from
(select a.item_id, sum(a.quantity_required) quantity_required
from tms.item_requirements a
group by a.item_id) AA
inner join 
(select b.id, b.code, b.sub_code, b.name, b.specification, b.unit_qty_code_id 
 from tms.items b) BB on BB.id=AA.item_id
;

Comment: Have you tried replacing the alias `count` by someting less ambigious ?

Comment: Is the query you've shared here exactly what it generates? I don't see how all the AA and BB came to be, from the code you posted. If you've made edits before posting, those might accidentally change something.

Comment: This is the query for the above case

 (select a.item_id, sum(a.quantity_required) quantity_required from tms.item_requirements a group by a.item_id) AA inner join (select b.id, b.code, b.sub_code, b.name, b.specification, b.unit_qty_code_id from tms.items b)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with 
`item_requirements.*`.
`.*` is not supported by cake ORM.

You can use `->autoFields(true)` option. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513684/7966173) answer